# How to find a iOS/mac OS X framework via Cmake

Tags: xcode, boost, cmake

**Context**

I packaged Boost C++ libraries into a framework (for iOS) via this [script](https://github.com/davidandreoletti/boostoniphone-generic). The script produces **boost.framework**. The framework works fine when linked into an "hand made" Xcode project to build an iOS app.

**Problem**

I have another Xcode project (to build an iOS app) which requires boost.framework. This project uses CMake to generate Xcode project and then compile the iOS app. CMake does have support for framework, however, I have not beeen able to get boost.framework recognised by Cmake via my custom FindBoostFramework.cmake file.

FYI: CMake's builtin FindBoost.cmake does not find boost framework. My boost.framework is not located in standard locations (e.g. /System/Library/Framework ) but rather at something along the line of "/Users/Me/Dev/boost.framework".

Does any one know get CmMke find this framework ?

Environment:
OS: 10.8
Xcode: 4.4
Cmake 2.8.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out CMAKE_FRAMEWORK_PATH did NOT contain the directory path containing the framework sought.

Comment: This is old, but is this still working? I manage to find the framework when doing this, but then Findboost.cmake tries to read the version from version.hpp which does not exist, and cmake ends up failing.